# DiscordJS - выдать роль пользователю

Tags: javascript

Всем привет, мне каким то образом нужно выдать роль пользователю но понять как это сделать я не могу, просьба помочь разобраться.

````
const events = {
    MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD: 'messageReactionAdd',
    MESSAGE_REACTION_REMOVE: 'messageReactionRemove',
};


bot.on('raw', async event => {
    // `event.t` is the raw event name
    if(event.t == 'MESSAGE_REACTION_REMOVE' || event.t == 'MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD') {

        const { d: data } = event;
        const user = await bot.users.fetch(data.user_id);
        //const channel = bot.channels.cache.get(data.channel_id);
        // if the message is already in the cache, don't re-emit the event

        const message = await bot.channels.cache.get(data.channel_id).messages.fetch(data.message_id);
        //console.log(message.reactions.message);
        

        const emoji = data.emoji.name;
            // This gives us the reaction we need to emit the event properly, in top of the message object
        const reaction = message.reactions.cache.get(emoji);
        //console.log(message);
        bot.emit(events[event.t], reaction, user);

        // custom emojis reactions are keyed in a `name:ID` format, while unicode emojis are keyed by names
        // if you're on the master/v12 branch, custom emojis reactions are keyed by their ID
        
    }
});


bot.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
    if (reaction.message.id == "772763833479069708" || reaction.message.id ==  "772762865169727528") {
            var message = reaction.message;
            if (reaction.emoji.name == "✅") {
                //user.setVoiceChannel("772762092096192543");
                var role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id === "772867338470293534");
                
                user.send('Вы подтвердили свою личность теперь вы авторизированный ✅ пользователь!')

                //console.log(reaction);
            }
            if (reaction.emoji.name == "") {
                let myRole = message.guild.roles.cache.get("772867093023555605");
                
                user.send("Вам была выдана роль - Leader");
            }
            if (reaction.emoji.name == "") {
                let myRole = message.guild.roles.cache.get("772866912551174195");

                user.send("Вам была выдана роль - Player");
            }
    }
});


bot.on('messageReactionRemove', (reaction, user) => {
                    
    if (reaction.message.id == "772763833479069708" || reaction.message.id ==  "772762865169727528") {
     

            var message = reaction.message;

            if (reaction.emoji.name == "✅") {
                let myRole = message.guild.roles.cache.get("772867338470293534");
                user.send("Вы отказались от правил нашего дискорд сервера , група ✅ Verify была удалена!");
            }
            if (reaction.emoji.name == "") {
                let myRole = message.guild.roles.cache.get("772867093023555605");
                user.send("Роль Leader была удалена!");
            }
            if (reaction.emoji.name == "") {
                let myRole = message.guild.roles.cache.get("772866912551174195");
                userr.send("Роль Player была удалена!");
            }

        }

   

});  ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

const myGuilds = bot.guilds.cache.get(event.d.guild_id);
var role = "772867093023555605";
myGuilds.members.fetch(userID).then(member => member.roles.add(myGuilds.roles.cache.get(role))).catch(console.error);

Answer (score 1):

Здесь, GuildMember - это участник сервера, а RoleResolvable - роль. Все просто :D

```
<GuildMember>.roles.add(<RoleResolvable>);
```